# SQL Server Count Query with no order

Tags: sql

I have a series of select count queries tied together by UNION egg

```
Select Count(Column1) From Table1 where Table1 column1 = 1
union 
Select Count(Column2) From Table1 where Table1 column2 = 1
```

It works fine but it just orders in asc or desc order but I want it to go in order by which I requested, I want the first query to always be first in the result no matter what the value is. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt, 1 AS SortOrder FROM Table1 WHERE column1 = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt, 2 AS SortOrder FROM Table1 WHERE column2 = 1 
ORDER BY SortOrder
```

The main change I have made is to add a column which you can use to ORDER BY. Some of the other changes I have made:

- You don't mean `UNION`, you mean `UNION ALL`. Otherwise with your query if the counts were the same you'd only get one row. In the new query this wouldn't happen, but you should still use UNION ALL because that's semantically what you mean.
- Writing `COUNT(column1)` is unnecessary because your WHERE clause guarantees that column1 can never be NULL. Use `COUNT(*)`. I imagine that even if you write `COUNT(column1)` most databases will see that column1 cannot be NULL and omit the unnecessary NULL check, but again there is nothing wrong with being explicit - you want to count all rows and `COUNT(*)` makes that clear.
- You shouldn't have `Table1 column1` with a space between. There should be a dot. Or simply omit the table name as it is not required here.

Answer (score 3):

Run two queries?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a column and sort on it

```
Select 1 as sequence, Count(Column1) From Table1 where Table1 column1 = 1
union 
Select 2 as sequence, Count(Column2) From Table1 where Table1 column2 = 1
ORDER BY sequence
```